# drawing graphics and event handling

Tags: java, graphics, event-handling, jframe, actionlistener

I am trying to write a program that draws a circle on the screen then gives you 3 buttons (red, yellow, and Green) and clicking the button changes the fill color of the circle accordingly.

I think I'm close, I just don't know how actually to create a method that will draw the circle and change the color. I can write a method to draw and fill a circle I'm just having problems merging it with jbutton

This is what i have so far:

(ignore the unused imports)

---

took a different approach, i don't know if it's any better. My buttons display and everything just having problems changing the color. Actually right now i cant even display a circle. i know i need to call `repaint();` in my eventhandler im just not sure how to do it. This is due Sunday ive spent so many hours watching videos and reading example i just cant get mine to work. I'm sure its stupid simple but it frustrating that heck out of me!

```
  public class test3 extends JPanel {

JRadioButton RED, YELLOW, GREEN; 
Color currentColor;          


public void paintComponent(Graphics g){

    currentColor= Color.RED; 

        super.paintComponent(g);
        this.setBackground(Color.WHITE);

        g.setColor(currentColor);
        g.fillOval(50, 50, 100, 100);    
       }






public static void main(String[] args) {

  test3 frame = new test3();
  frame.setSize(500,500);

  frame.setVisible(true);
    }

public test3 (){

JPanel jpRadioButtons=new JPanel();
jpRadioButtons.setLayout(new GridLayout(1,1));
jpRadioButtons.add(RED=new JRadioButton("RED"));
jpRadioButtons.add(GREEN=new JRadioButton("GREEN"));
jpRadioButtons.add(YELLOW=new JRadioButton("YELLOW"));

add(jpRadioButtons, BorderLayout.SOUTH);


ButtonGroup group=new ButtonGroup();
group.add(RED);
group.add(YELLOW);
group.add(GREEN);

GREEN.addActionListener(new ActionListener()
{
    public void actionPerormed(ActionEvent e)
    {        

        currentColor = Color.GREEN;
     repaint();           
    }
      });

   }
}
```

Comment: Have you gone through the [Swing drawing tutorials](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/painting/index.html) yet? That's where I'd start since if you don't know how to draw a circle, you're dead in the water. Hint: you're missing the most important method, `paintComponent(...)`.

Answer (score 1):

1. Introduce a class variable/property/... with the current color of the circle.
2. Set this variable in your eventhandler
3. Also call "repaint();" in your eventhandler
4. Override the `paintComponent()` method and make it draw a circle in the color, which you can read from the class variable.

Your `paintComponent(Graphics g)` might look something like this:

```
@Override
void paintComponent(Graphics g)
{
  g.setColor(currentColor);
  g.drawOval(50,50,100,100);
}
```

Comment: all of my code didn't get copied in the original post i apologize for that. I already have "paintComponent" class... Im still unsure how to use the "repaint()" method. Do i need to pass in parameters? Do i override "paintComponet() in my eventhandler class?

Comment: i edited the original post to include my "paintComponet" class

Comment: @user1789951: you need to set the color via a variable as Simon "says" (1+ to Simon), not hard-code it to `Color.blue` as you are doing. And no, event handler's don't have paintComopnent methods. Only classes that derive from JComponent such as JPanel. You should up-vote Simon's answer (as I have done) since it is very helpful.

Comment: You can call `repaint();` just like that, without parameters, after changing the variable, to force a repaint of the circle with the new color. And, as HovercraftFullOfEels already explained, you declared the `paintComponent` method in the right place.

Comment: can anyone go further into the repaint method? i still dont quite understand? a code example maybe?... i have my paintComponet method and i set the color to a variable "currentColor" and use that to paint. Then in my action listener i just change the current color varible to the color i want and call "repaint();" i cant get it to work

Comment: Feel free to update the original question with the new code. Also, make sure that you call the `repaint` method on the Panel you want to repaint. Just to be clear: You don't have to add a variable to `paintComponent` and you don't have to set a variable. `paintComponent` should just use the variable to paint the circle in the correct color.

Comment: im sure this is very simple i just cant apply it i don't know. I updated the code i have now. I cant get this to work

Comment: Change the spelling mistake in `actionPerormed`. You also don't want to change the value of `currentColor` in the `paintComponent` method. As a general rule, you should add the line `@Override` above all methods you want to override from the superclass (like `actionPerformed`, `paintComponent`). This will help you catch spelling mistakes.